# Login and scrape a site that uses CORS(AWS) and JS to populate itself with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, authentication, google-apps-script, web-scraping

I am trying to access the following Japanese site and scrape data from a table, but I am struggling to login using Google Apps Script. I need to use a solution that does not rely on a desktop and can be done completely online. I am not that experienced with web development/web scraping, so I'm basically learning as I go.

I have the username and password, but:

1. I am unable to figure out what headers I need to send to login. I get 403 errors when using the actual url, https://calllog-dev.123robo.com/#/login, and 502 when using the request url from the browser, https://dbp3xa4g5g.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/users/authenticate

2.The login page uses CORS and AWS api to Authenticate, so there are no cookies until I have successfully logged in and send a GET request via browser.

3.There are multple tokens: x-logview-token which is within the response to the POST request for logging in, and a Page Token is generated for each page.

Response to Login Post Request:

```
    {"username":"user@gmail.com","token":"this-is-the-token-value","enableDigits":true}
```

I am thinking of using cookies from the browser's GET Request to recreate it and send it through Google Apps Scripts. Is there someway to bypass the login or use the cookies to login?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge">
  <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel=icon href=/favicon.ico>
  <link rel=stylesheet href=//cdn.materialdesignicons.com/3.4.93/css/materialdesignicons.min.css>
  <title>123ROBO 通話履歴</title>
  <link href=/css/app.5339eed8.css rel=preload as=style>
  <link href=/css/chunk-vendors.8b9ade74.css rel=preload as=style>
  <link href=/js/app.32f2c21e.js rel=preload as=script>
  <link href=/js/chunk-vendors.cd62bd72.js rel=preload as=script>
  <link href=/css/chunk-vendors.8b9ade74.css rel=stylesheet>
  <link href=/css/app.5339eed8.css rel=stylesheet>
</head>

<body><noscript><strong>We're sorry but logview doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong></noscript>
  <div id=app></div>
  <script src=/js/chunk-vendors.cd62bd72.js></script>
  <script src=/js/app.32f2c21e.js></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the website: https://calllog-dev.123robo.com/#/login

Here is the Code I have been trying to use:

```
function loginTest(){

//Added Basic Authorization
  var userID = 'user@gmail.com';
                  
  var userPW = 'password'  ;
 
  var url = 'https://dbp3xa4g5g.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/users/authenticate';
  
  //Added a body as pointed out by Mark. Added Request Headers as suggested by pguardiario
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             'authority': 'dbp3xa4g5g.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
              'path': '/dev/users/authenticate',
              'scheme': 'https',
              'accept': '*/*',
              'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
              'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ja;q=0.8',
              'content-type': 'application/json',
              'origin': 'https://calllog-dev.123robo.com',
              'referer': 'https://calllog-dev.123robo.com/',
              'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
              'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
              'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
              'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36',
             },
               
  
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
  
  Logger.log(response);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText("UTF-8"));
  
}
```

Comment: I refreshed the page with the Chrome Developers tools open and found requests that have cookies (including session cookies) in them! Also there are multiple GET responses that have the JS contained in them. I think this is an important detail, but I don't know if/how I should try to use the cookies to gain access or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just send an `Authorization` header, when it expects a `body`:

```
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
  }
```

And this page has one general DOM issue, along with some typos:

> [DOM] Password field is not contained in a form: (More info: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/create-amazing-password-forms)
> `<input type=​"password" autocomplete=​"on" class=​"input">​`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have implemented the code you suggested, but still get the 403 error. I have updated the code in the question to reflect what I executed.

Also yes, I noticed there was no form within the HTML. Nothing I can do about it, unfortunately.

Comment: That page gives me a 304 ...and this is exactly how the site posts the login. Most likely this site is Laravel, with all the web-pack chunks loaded, so this might be: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication ...but there is no CSFR token present in DOM (as it is supposed to be), so it should be relatively easy.

Comment: Hmmm...interesting I've never gotten a 304. I know nothing about laravel, but I didn't see anything on the site I could recognize that suggests that it uses laravel...
Could you elaborate on how it should be easy to login?

Comment: Key should be `payload` and not `body`. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/urlfetch/info) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

That's the wrong url, take a look:
[image]

Comment: Your right, the request is being sent to that url instead of the website itself. I changed it to the request URL and tried to run it, getting a 502 Bad Gateway error. I think I need a token of some kind to access it. I adjusted the code in the question to reflect what I executed.

Comment: Try copying the browser request headers and send them too (esp referer). Lose the authorization header.

Comment: I still got the 502 error, unfortunately. Here are the request headers, copied from when I successfully logged in using Chrome:


authority: dbp3xa4g5g.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
:method: POST
:path: /dev/users/authenticate
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ja;q=0.8

content-type: application/json
origin: https://calllog-dev.123robo.com
referer: https://calllog-dev.123robo.com/
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0...Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36

Comment: To add, there is also a token I found in the response to a GET request after successfully logging in called x-logview-token. The GET request has similar headers to teh POST request, but uses this URL: https://dbp3xa4g5g.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/calls/log?PageSize=10&Page=0&digits=true

Comment: I'm out of ideas, I was going to suggest not sending the h2 headers (the ones with a : in them), I don't think it will help though. Maybe h2 is important or maybe the cors pre-flight is important or maybe they're just blocking traffic from apps script.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your contributions. I will try to do something with the cookies produced  from sending GET requests while logged in.